# Image Blend Modes in Android Studio (Like photoshop, paint.net)?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, porter-duff, blend-mode

I am trying to blend two images the same way **photoshop** or **paint.net** blend them, with different blend modes like `Difference, Multiply, Additive, Color Burn, Glow, etc.`

I have found that `PorterDuff.Mode` works quite well, but it lacks blending effects ( it only has Add, Multiply, screen) is there a way to get a bigger range of blend modes? Is there a way to edit the  `android.graphics.PorterDuff;` library to get more blend modes?
Any ideas?

For example:
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amLU6.png)
turns into this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psjrE.png)

This is the porterduff code im using btw:

```
private static Bitmap Result(Bitmap bottomImage, Bitmap topImage){


    int sizex = bottomImage.getWidth();
    int sizey = bottomImage.getHeight();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sizex, sizey , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(imageBitmap);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(bottomImage, 0f, 0f, paint);;
    PorterDuff.Mode mode = PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY;//Porterduff MODE
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(mode));

    Bitmap ScaledtopImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(topImage, sizex, sizey, false);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(ScaledtopImage, 0f, 0f, paint);

    return imageBitmap;

}
```

Comment: have you got any proper method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert on image processing but PorterDuff has some blending modes, namely darken, lighten, multiply, screen and overlay. You can then use the in, atop, xor, etc to get the selection you want of the blended sections.

http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode